# MySQL Circular References in One-to-Many Relation: Is there a way to avoid it?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider following as an example:

I have a `User` table which contains user's information along with a `PrimaryAddress` column that references `Address` table.

The `Address` table, contains address information along with a `UserId` column which refers to who the address belongs to.

Each user can have many addresses, but only one address can be `PrimaryAddress`. Therefore, the `User` table needs to store a reference to `PrimaryAddress` to enforce this rule. Having a `IsPrimary` column in address table would not have a similar effect.

But as you can tell, this will create a circular relation between User and Address tables and circular dependencies can be a sign of bad design as far as I'm aware. The question is, is there a way to avoid this? If so, how?

Comment: You could have another table `User_Primary_Addresses` that contains foreign keys to `User` and `Addresses`. But then you have the possibility of a user not being in that table and having no primary address. But if the `User.PrimaryAddress` column is nullable, it's equivalent.

Comment: Agreed with barmar.  Create a "Link" or "Mapping" table.... with a FK from both sides.  if its a single relationship put a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the 2 FK columns on the Link/Mapping table.  You can remove it "later" if the rules change.

Comment: Circular references are not always bad. Sometimes they're unavoidable.

Comment: you can omit the PrimaryAddress column from User and just have a Primary boolean in the Address table, with a unique constraint to enforce that only one address per user is set primary (this is not completely straightforward to do but regularly gets asked for here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circular reference is not necessarily a "bad" design. You gave an example of a real-world case that has legitimate meaning.

I admit it's a little bit complex to manage. The `User.PrimaryAddress` must be nullable, if you need to create a user row before you create the address you will eventually designate as the primary address.

Also if you need an SQL script to recreate the database, you can add foreign key constraints only after the referenced table is created. So you have a chicken-and-egg problem if you have circular references. The typical solution is to create tables without their foreign keys, then once they are created, add the foreign keys using `ALTER TABLE`.

The workarounds all sacrifice something. If you add an attribute `Address.IsPrimary`, then you have to figure out how to ensure that exactly one address per user is primary. If you use a third table, you have to worry that it is missing a row for each user.

The circular reference may be the *least* problematic solution.

Answer (score 1):

no you would use a bridge4 table in combination with a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`

This will also help, if a address can have multiple users

That would then look like

> ```
> CREATE tABLE user (id int PRIMARY KEY)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user VALUEs(1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe address(id int PRIMARY KEY)
> ```

> ```
> INSERt INTO address VALUES(1),(2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_address ( user_id int, address_id int, Is_primary int
> ,FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
>         REFERENCES user(id)
>         ,FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
>         REFERENCES address(id)
>         ,PRIMARY KEY (user_id,address_id)
>
> )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_user_address_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON user_address FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE rowcount INT;
>     IF NEW.Is_primary = 1 then
>         SELECT COUNT(*) 
>         INTO rowcount
>         FROM user_address WHERE user_id = NEw.user_id AND Is_primary = 1;
>     
>         IF rowcount = 1 THEN
>         set @message_text = CONCAT('userid ',New.user_id ,' has already a primary address');
>             SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
>         END IF; 
>     end if;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user_address VALUEs(1,1,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user_address VALUEs(1,2,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> userid 1 has already a primary address
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7b4429a52850c618a0938a54572010f)*